# TomSelect - refresh options in dependent Dropdown after repeated ajax load

Tags: javascript, php, tom-select

Im using [TomSelect](https://tom-select.js.org/) to control my `<select>` UI for my dependent select dropdowns.

[image]

The `<option>...</option>` list of the `To` dropdown depends on the `From` dropdown and is updated per ajax call on the selection in the `From` dropdown. The first initialization works fine on both dropdowns. Unfortunately, after repeating the ajax request through selecting another location on the `From` dropdown results in the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Tom Select already initialized on this element
```

What i did so far:

**1.** On page load i'm initializing TomSelect on the `From` dropdown with:

```
tsfrom = new TomSelect('#from-select-field',ttddssettings);
```

[image]

**The relevant lines of code:**

```
    <select id="from-select-field" name="from" onchange="getTo();">  
    <option value='0'>Choose...</option>
    </select>

    <select id="to-select-field" name="from">  
        <option value='0'>Select From first</option>
    </select>

    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            
            var tsfrom;     
            var ttddssettings = {   
                plugins: ['dropdown_input'],
            };
            tsfrom = new TomSelect('#from-select-field',ttddssettings);
            
            var totoval = "xymydomain.com/get-to-options.php";              
            getTo = function () {

                var fromvalue = $("#from-select-field").val();
                var tovalue = $("#to-select-field").val();
            
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: totoval,           
                    data: {
                        from: fromvalue,
                        to: tovalue,                                
                    },                                          
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#to-select-field").html(data);
                    },                      
                });
            }

        });

    </script>
```

**The relevant lines of code inside the requested PHP file:**

```
    <?php               
        $sql_to = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE ..... ORDER by names ASC";                     

        $quer_to = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql_to);
        $quer_to->execute();
        $fetch_to_values = $quer_to->fetchAll();                                        
        
        foreach ( $fetch_to_values as $tovalues ) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $tovalue['name']; ?>" <?php if ( $tovalue['name'] == $to) { echo "selected";} ?>><?php echo $tovalue['name']; ?></option>                                 
    
    <?php } ?>

    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            
            var tsto;       
            var tttossettings = {   
                plugins: ['dropdown_input'],
            };
            tsto = new TomSelect('#to-select-field',tttossettings);

        });

    </script>
```

**2.** After selcting a `From` location the `To` dropdown gets populated per ajax. The requested file (see above) through ajax `url:` includes **also** the following code to initialize TomSelect on the `To` dropdown:

```
tsto = new TomSelect('#to-select-field',tttossettings);
```

[image]

So far everything works fine.

**3. THE PROBLEM:**

As mentioned before, after repeatedly selecting a different location on the `From` dropdown i get the error `Tom Select already initialized on this element`.

The [TomSelect DOCS](https://tom-select.js.org/docs/api/#refreshoptionstriggerdropdown) mentioning `refreshOptions(triggerDropdown)` (Refreshes the list of available options shown in the autocomplete dropdown menu.). Unfortunately I have no idea if this is the right approach or how to fix this. **Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two changes should get rid of the error:

**Remove script block from PHP page:**

Get rid of the `<script>` block in your PHP file and only return the `<option>...</option>` values. This is also messy as you are setting the HTML of the `<select>` to be what the PHP code has generated, including the returned script block.

**Trigger updating the drop down in the AJAX success block**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: totoval,           
    data: {
        from: fromvalue,
        to: tovalue,                                
    },                                          
    success: function(data) {
        $("#to-select-field").html(data);
        tsto.clear(); // unselect previously selected elements
        tsto.clearOptions(); // remove existing options
        tsto.sync(); // synchronise with the underlying SELECT
    },                      
});
```

Using the [`sync`](https://tom-select.js.org/docs/api/#sync) method should update the styled dropdown options based on the underlying `<select>`.

Alternatively, calling `tsfrom.refreshOptions();` instead of `sync()` could also work.

Comment: hi, thx - changed `tsfrom.sync();` to `tsto.sync();` but it keeps some old options... tried to add `cleaCache()` before snyc nothing changed...

Comment: @evavienna ah, sure, it should have been `tsto`. It seems `sync()` is not sufficient as can be seen in this [Github issue](https://github.com/orchidjs/tom-select/issues/362). I'll update the code in my answer.

Comment: @SaschM78 - seems to work but it also removes the first option which is my placeholder which says "Choose.." so the select field collapses due to missing optiona after sync - any way to ignore the first option? Thx a lot for your help!

Comment: How about returning an empty option tag also from your PHP page? I.e. as first output, generate a `<option value="">Choose ...</option>`?

Comment: thx a lot so far. Accepted the answer. best